# Create a column based on values in a dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark, etl

I have a dictionary like this:

```py
sample_dict = {
    "A": ["aaaa\.com", "aaaa\.es"],
    "B": ["bbbb\.com", "bbbb\.es", "bbbb\.net"],
    "C": ["ccccc\.com"],
    # many more entries here
}
```

I would like to add a column in a Spark DataFrame which performs the following operation:

```py
(
    df
    .withColumn(
        "new_col",
        F.when(
            (F.col("filter_col").rlike("aaaa\.com")) | 
            (F.col("filter_col").rlike("aaaa\.es")),
            F.lit("A") 
        )
        .when(
            (F.col("filter_col").rlike("bbbb\.com")) | 
            (F.col("filter_col").rlike("bbbb\.es")) | 
            (F.col("filter_col").rlike("bbbb\.net")),
            F.lit("B") 
        )
        .when(
            (F.col("filter_col").rlike("cccc\.com")),
            F.lit("C") 
        )
        .otherwise(None)
    )
)
```

But, of course, I would like it to be dynamical, so that I may add new components to my dictionary and the column would automatically consider them and add a new category based on the rules.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the column expression by iterating over the `dict` and assign this expression to your `withColumn` call.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sample_dict = {
    "A": ["aaaa\.com", "aaaa\.es"],
    "B": ["bbbb\.com", "bbbb\.es", "bbbb\.net"],
    "C": ["ccccc\.com"],
    # many more entries here
}

data = [("aaaa.com", ), ("aaaa.es", ), ("bbbb.com", ), ("zzzz.com", ), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("filter_col", ))

column_expression = F
for k, conditions in sample_dict.items():
    condition_expression = F.col("filter_col").rlike(conditions[0])
    for condition in conditions[1:]:
        condition_expression |= F.col("filter_col").rlike(condition)
    column_expression = column_expression.when(condition_expression, F.lit(k))

df.withColumn("new_col", column_expression.otherwise(None)).show()
```

### Output

```
# column_expression Equivalent to writing the expression by hand
Column<'CASE WHEN (RLIKE(filter_col, aaaa\.com) OR RLIKE(filter_col, aaaa\.es)) THEN A WHEN ((RLIKE(filter_col, bbbb\.com) OR RLIKE(filter_col, bbbb\.es)) OR RLIKE(filter_col, bbbb\.net)) THEN B WHEN RLIKE(filter_col, ccccc\.com) THEN C END'>


## Df with expression applied
+----------+-------+
|filter_col|new_col|
+----------+-------+
|  aaaa.com|      A|
|   aaaa.es|      A|
|  bbbb.com|      B|
|  zzzz.com|   null|
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: I like this version because it does not require me to adapt the original format of the dictionary (one key can hold a list of multiple regex patterns). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you could alter you column such that you could look for exact matches you could use `df.replace()`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(filter_col='aaa.de'),
    Row(filter_col='aaa.es'),
    Row(filter_col='bbb.de'),
    Row(filter_col='bbb.es'),
])

d = {
    'aaa.de': 'A',
    'aaa.es': 'A',
    'bbb.de': 'B',
    'bbb.es': 'B',
}

(
    df
    .withColumn('new_col', F.col('filter_col'))
    .withColumn('new_col', F.when(F.col('new_col').isin(list(d.keys())), F.col('new_col')))
    .replace(d, None, subset='new_col')
    .show()
)

# Output:
+----------+-------+
|filter_col|new_col|
+----------+-------+
|    aaa.de|      A|
|    aaa.es|      A|
|    bbb.de|      B|
|    bbb.es|      B|
|       foo|   null|
+----------+-------+
```

There might be a more performant way to replace values not mentioned in your dictionary with "None" (your "otherwise" condition).

---

#### Update:

If the reformatting is not possible, you would have to iterate through your dict:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(filter_col='aaa.de/foo'),
    Row(filter_col='aaa.es/foo'),
    Row(filter_col='bbb.de/foo'),
    Row(filter_col='bbb.es/foo'),
    Row(filter_col='foo'),
])

d = {
    'aaa\.de': 'A',
    'aaa\.es': 'A',
    'bbb\.de': 'B',
    'bbb\.es': 'B',
}

df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.lit(None).cast('string'))
for k,v in d.items():
    df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.when(F.col('filter_col').rlike(k), v).otherwise(F.col('new_col')))
    
df.show()
# Output
+----------+-------+
|filter_col|new_col|
+----------+-------+
|aaa.de/foo|      A|
|aaa.es/foo|      A|
|bbb.de/foo|      B|
|bbb.es/foo|      B|
|       foo|   null|
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. My example is a bit simpler than my actual use case, which includes a more complex regex. I can't simply extract all posible values in "filter_col", I need the regex to match

Comment: Yes, I just realized that the `rlike` does more than just find exact matches.

Comment: Maybe write a UDF to do what you want? https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

Comment: Alternatively to UDF, you can programmatically build the `F.when` etc.. chain from your dictionary in a function, and return it for use by withColumn.

Comment: @itscarlayall: similar to Hitobat's suggestion I extended my answer

Comment: This will not be very performant though when your dictionary becomes very large.

Comment: Seems like I will have to go with the loop option! I was looking for a more "sparky" way of doing it, sort of like when you create multiple columns in an aggregation using a list comprehension. But this does the job just fine for my regex dict :)